# guarantee of reinterpret_cast output for serialization purpose

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[5] = { 0 };
    buffer[0] = 23;

    std::string s(&buffer[0], 4);
    std::uint32_t nb = *reinterpret_cast<const std::uint32_t*>(s.data());

    return 0;
}
```

For this program, is reinterpret_cast's output implementation dependent? Or will any compiler conforming to the c++ standard always produce the same output?

Comment: IIRC this can cause alignment problems.

Comment: That's usually one of the worst ideas you can have.

Comment: dyp:reinterpret_cast cannot cast a constant

Comment: then why not `const_cast<char*>(s.data())`

Comment: After the last edits, I think only alignment might be an issue.

Comment: The Standard guarantees that you can *copy* the underlying bytes of an object which is trivially copyable (C++11) into an array of `char` and *copy* them back safely [basic.types]/2. The example given there uses `memcpy`. IIRC `reinterpret_cast` has mostly implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: the implementation of reintrepet_cast can output the bytes in an different order than the order of the input bytes ?

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is guaranteed to *work* if `s.data()` is suitable alligned (highly likely). In practice, it will also *work* if there's no internal difference between a `char*` and a `uint32_t*` (also highly likely). The only other chance for bad things happening is on the actual dereference.

Comment: @dyp shouldn't reinterpret_cast always be a no-op, whatever the implementation is ?

Comment: @Deduplicator So, what about evil optimizations?

Comment: @dyp: Those don't matter. Aliasing in this case is allowed.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know that you can alias an object of any type with a `char` type, but this `reinterpret_cast` uses the inverse direction: The object has `char` type, and a new pointer is created with type `int const*`.

Comment: @dyp: Where do you see any trouble there, if alignment fits? Ah, found one interesting bit: The fixed-width types are not guaranteed to not have trap representations / non-value bits, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think there's any problem with the semantics if the alignment requirements are satisfied, but I think it might be UB under 3.10/10 and therefore potentially problematic wrt optimizations.

Comment: @dyp: Why? It's of type `uint32_t`, even if it was used as a `char[5]` earlier.

Comment: @Deduplicator Where did the object change its type to `uint32_t`? A cast doesn't change the type of an object, it merely changes the type of an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example code, if you're looking for something that "any compiler conforming to the c++ standard always produce the same output", the answer is that there's no such guarantee.

A couple easy examples: alignment issues (as mentioned in several comments) and endianness differences.

C++11 5.2.10/7  "Reinterpret cast" says:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is
>   `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout
>   types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than
>   those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no
>   stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspecified.

Since `uint32_t` will generally have a stricter alignment requirement than `char[]`, the standard doesn't make any promises about the behavior (since the above only talks about the situation where the alignment requirements are met). So strictly speaking the behavior is undefined.

Now, lets assume that you're interested only in platforms where the alignment requirements are met (ie., `uint32_t` can be aligned on any address, same as `char`). Then your expression involving the reinterpret cast is equivalent to (note that you'd have to cast away the `const` from the `const char*` returned from `std::string::data()` as well):

```
std::uint32_t nb = *(static_cast<std::uint32_t*>(static_cast<void*>(const_cast<char*>(s.data()))));
```

The standard says this about using `static_cast` with object pointers (other than conversion between pointers in a class heirarchy) in 5.2.9/13 "Static cast":

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `void`” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to *cv2* `T`,” where `T` is an object type and *cv2* is the
>   same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. The
>   null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>   destination type. A value of type pointer to object converted to
>   “pointer to *cv* `void`” and back, possibly with different
>   cv-qualification, shall have its original value.

So, as far as the standard is concerned, all that you can do with the resulting pointer is cast it back to get the original value. Anything else would be undefined behavior (that an implementation might give a better guarantee on).

3.10/10 "Lvalues and rvalues" allows an object to be accessed through `char` or `unsigned char` types as well.

However, to reiterate: the standard does not guarantee that "any compiler conforming to the c++ standard always produce the same output" for the example you posted.

Comment: *"note that you'd have to cast away the `const` from the `const char*` returned from `std::string::data()` as well*" Originally, OP used a C-style cast to perform this `const_cast`, OP then changed it to cast to `uint32_t const*` so the `const_cast` is not required any more.

Comment: Since this answer is in the direction of formally-pedantic: the conclusion "all that you can do with the resulting pointer is cast it back to get the original value", while accidentally correct for the standard's guarantees about the code in question, *does not follow* from the quoted standardese. Indeed, the C++ standard explicitly supports the C technique of casting a pointer to first item of a struct type T, to T*, and vice versa. That's not the practical case at hand, but it directly contradicts the logic, that is it contradicts the use of §5.2.9/13 as a rationale for the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

You're casting to `std::uint32_t` a buffer that is not necessarily properly aligned for such a value.

That's likely to blow up and/or be hugely inefficient.

The unsigned integer type means that any bitpattern for the value representation bits is OK, and on the PC platform for built-in type there are no bits other than the value representation bits; in particular no trap bits or trapping total bitpatterns.

Thus, you can do a `memcpy` and you'll be fine, *technically* – provided there are enough bytes, that `s.length() >= sizeof(std::uint32_t)`.

However, such a conversion, if it occurred in ordinary code, would be a strong code-smell, an indication of something fundamentally wrong in the design.

---

**Addendum**, regarding “Or a compiler respectfull to the c++ standard will always produce the same output”.

I somehow didn’t see that when I answered. But the short answer is that if the conversion is performed in a way that works, such as using `memcpy`, then it depends on the *endianness*, a.k.a. *byte order*, in practice whether the most significant or least significant part of an integer is placed at lowest address.

In practice you can use network-oriented functions that convert to from *network byte order*. Just assume network byte order for the serialized data. Check out `ntohl` et al (these are not part of the C++ standard library, but commonly available).

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by a char* that is not properly aligned ? I well understand the alignement problem for a structure and the use of padding bytes but don't see what does it mean for a sequence of byte pointed by a char*. You mean that the buffer[5] can be in fine aligned on 8 bytes ? (Yes i know for memcpy, my open question is just for educational purpose)

Comment: @Guillaume07: okay let's break it down. `s.data()` gives pointer to internal string buffer, which can be a "small buffer optimization" internal buffer not allocated by the standard allocator. thus, although far fetched it can be at an odd address. it's reinterpreted as pointer to `uint32_t`. that `uint32_t*`pointer is dereferenced. the `uint32_t` value now assumed to be residing in the string's internal buffer, starting at an odd address, is attempted copied. that would most likely trap, which might cause program termination or a slow fix-up.

Comment: Doesn't libc++ use first byte of `string` for the size and the remaining 23 bytes for the data under SSO? That would imply that the buffer is aligned at a `size_t` boundary plus one byte.

Comment: The compiler can already blow things on the cast from `char*` to `uint32_t*`. No need to wait for the dereference (though most platforms, unless ancient, don't break that early).

Comment: @dyp: First byte for size and rest for SSO on big-endian. Other way around on little-endian. So Big-Endian will be misaligned...